# Print dictionary containing accuracy, precision, recall and F1-score for each query

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a sample dataset as following. all the features are categorical, and the label is binary of 0 and 1.

I applied decision trees for a classification problem. the question is how to print Dictionary named `query_results` containing accuracy, precision, recall and F1-score for each query in the evaluation set as `{'query1':{'accuracy':value,'precision':value,...},'query2':{...}}`

Expected Result:

```
{'query1':{'accuracy':value,'precision':value,...},'query2':{...}}

{"t-shirt": 'accuracy': 90% ,'precision':91%, "recall" : 90%, "F1_score" :90%  
shoes : 'accuracy': 90% ,'precision':91%, "recall" : 90%, "F1_score" :90%  
skirt : 'accuracy': 80% ,'precision':91%, "recall" : 90%, "F1_score" :90%
..  }
```

```
    query   price       product silhouette          brand   color   upper_material  pattern label
1   t-shirt low.        shoe    backless_slipper    Guess   schwarz   Kunststoff    unifarben   1
2   t-shirt low         shoe    backless_slipper    Tommy   red       Textil        gestreift   1
```

Comment: how you expecting the result can you add a demo result.

Comment: Thanks, yes I updated the question, I put the format.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = {"query1": {"Accuracy": "90", "Precision": "91", "Recall": "90"}, "query2": {"Accuracy": "90", "Precision": "94", "Recall": "90"}}
print(query1+' '+str(dictionary.get('query1')))
```

This is a common code use can loop it for more values.I have set a static values for this.for dynamic you can set a varible.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I am new to python, Ididnt get what you mean, can you please tell me clear?

Comment: I don't see in your code the 'accuracy':, precision, F1_score and ..

Comment: I don't know how extract even accuracy per query ..

Comment: Thanks you yid, Yes It would be nice becuse I don't know how to deal with the question

Comment: i think now it is more comfortable for you.